# Installing as 'root' is not currently supported - what should I do?

Tags: bash, root

I finally got root access to one of the nodes which incredibly helped me to get most of my software installed. But now, for the first time, I got into issues for actually being root :-))

```
We recommend running this script as a designated SMRT Analysis user
(e.g. smrtanalysis) who will own all smrtpipe jobs and daemon 
processes.  

Current user is 'root' (primary group: root)

Installing as 'root' is not currently supported
Switch to the desired user and restart the install.
Aborting installation...
```

I therefore tried to create new user, but I don't have enough privileges to do that:

```
/usr/local/bin$ sudo adduser smrtanalysis
Adding user `smrtanalysis' ...
Adding new group `smrtanalysis' (1001) ...
Adding new user `smrtanalysis' (1001) with group `smrtanalysis' ...
Creating home directory `/home/smrtanalysis' ...
Stopped: Couldn't create home directory `/home/smrtanalysis': Permission denied.

Removing directory `/home/smrtanalysis' ...
Removing user `smrtanalysis' ...
Removing group `smrtanalysis' ...
groupdel: group 'smrtanalysis' does not exist
adduser: `groupdel smrtanalysis' returned error code 6. Exiting.
```

Can I somehow use my own user - which is root - to install this software? How?

Comment: If your user is root, why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: @cjm: The `$` in the prompt *probably* implies that he's running as a non-`root` user, as does the fact that the "finally" got root access (so he must have had a non-`root` account before). It's just the phrase "my own user - which is root" which is confusing, and possibly misleading.

Comment: @cjm without sudo I don't have write permissions to /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you (as `root`) don't have permission to create `/home/smrtanalysis`, it probably means that `/home` is served from some other system on which you don't have root access.

Can you ask the administrator of that system to create the `smrtanalysis` account for you?

If not, you can probably use the `adduser --home` option to put the new account's home directory somewhere else; pick a location where you do have permission to create a directory (and that has enough available disk space). Assuming you have a non-`root` account on the system, a subdirectory of that account's home directory might be a good place.

But you should probably talk to your system administrator (presumably the person from whom you "finally got root access") about the best way to do this.

Comment: You are right, I used "sudo" to be able to create directories in /usr/local/bin and therefore could not use my user. This time I made the directory writable, ran the comment without sudo and it did not complain. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Perlnika: Then you're not following the installer's advice, which is to install the software as a dedicated user such as `smrtanalysis`, not as yourself. I'm not saying you *have* to do that, but if you're going to ignore that advice, be sure you have a good reason for doing so.

Comment: I know :/ Your advice is actually very good, but the reason why I asked for sudo permissions is that our admin is very busy and not very keen on helping us. Therefore I am trying to do as much as I can without bothering him.

Comment: @Perlnika: Ok, but you might still be able to create the `smrtanalysis` user account on your system. The configuration of `/home` prevents you from doing it straightforwardly, but you should be able to give the account a home directory somewhere else (that won't be shared with other nodes).